# Use googleAnalyticsR to get data about adwords campaigns

Tags: r, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

I am using the googleAnalyticsR package to retrieve google analytics data. If I connect to google analytics

```
ga_auth()
```

And get my account, web_prop_id and link_id I can check my adwords campaign with the following:

```
ga_adwords(account_id, webprop_id, linkId)
```

However, within this adwords campaign I want to see which ad-group gets which clicks. Any thoughts on how I can do this deepdive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the native GA reporting API to get click data from AdWords, details of all metrics and dimensions are [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets)

It would be something like:

```
library(googleAnalyticsR)
ga_auth()
ad_data <- google_analytics(123456, date_range = c("2016-03-02", "today"), 
                             metrics = c("adClicks", "adCost"),
                             dimensions = c("medium","campaign"))
```

Comment: slight change with the new version of the googleAnalyticsR library - in the code above replace google_analytics4 with google_analytics and "campaigns" with "campaign"

Comment: Has this changed? I receive zero data on AdWords metrics like adClicks and adCost. Only thing different is the view ID and the dates.

Comment: No it has not changed, perhaps check you are querying valid dims/metrics using the quick online query explorer https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/